# how to extract data from an xml with PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, xml

i'm working a project of units of learning, so i need to extract all the data from the xml, here's an example of one xml made with reload ld editor

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This is a Reload LD Editor version 2.1.3 IMS Learning Design 1.0 document-->
<!--Spawned from the Reload Learning Design Generator - http://www.reload.ac.uk-->
<manifest xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1" xmlns:imsld="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsld_v1p0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1.xsd http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsld_v1p0 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/IMS_LD_Level_A.xsd" identifier="manifest-7EE42F26-6089-C6C2-6847-BE6E7B7CCB53">
  <organizations>
<imsld:learning-design identifier="ld-56153381-4457-f4dd-ddd8-04b623b7b3ca" level="A" sequence-used="false" uri="http://www.reload.ac.uk/uri/ld-51460f5e-71bd-3950-fad2-7522c7018c2f" version="1">
  <imsld:title>prueba</imsld:title>
  <imsld:learning-objectives>
    <imsld:title>hacer pruebas</imsld:title>
    <imsld:item identifier="item-c9b554d7-9388-3f18-93a0-3a6a599d6d67" identifierref="resource-58164a05-d1a7-73a5-2fe9-5b3a0a9522be" isvisible="true">
      <imsld:title>pruebaoverview</imsld:title>
    </imsld:item>
  </imsld:learning-objectives>
  <imsld:components>
    <imsld:roles>
      <imsld:learner identifier="role-79d92c95-7ec4-0cc0-711a-963a476e2a63">
        <imsld:title>Alumno3</imsld:title>
        <imsld:information>
          <imsld:title>Alumno</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-6e199a21-f143-e27a-adbc-2ab2d2de391c" identifierref="resource-c7f25198-8dce-d046-4594-7a2b22b5dd15" isvisible="true" />
        </imsld:information>
      </imsld:learner>
      <imsld:staff identifier="role-0964b724-355c-49e8-a60f-58b444b29af4">
        <imsld:title>Asesor</imsld:title>
        <imsld:information>
          <imsld:title>Profesor1</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-7fe2de65-6412-0bb8-fcbe-caeb0e6abe20" identifierref="resource-f8de38c1-d7f8-a9a5-b7a4-c737d967daf1" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>profesor1</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:information>
      </imsld:staff>
      <imsld:staff identifier="role-859e8d69-def4-6421-d721-52f0dbd26897">
        <imsld:title>Tutor</imsld:title>
        <imsld:information>
          <imsld:title>Profesor2</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-d76d9e97-97d3-47bd-0dcb-d2a224a77cd4" identifierref="resource-37f8f529-49c1-552c-e0a4-8aa581d93aa5" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>profesor2</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:information>
      </imsld:staff>
    </imsld:roles>
    <imsld:activities>
      <imsld:learning-activity identifier="la-ce439085-5259-457c-bb05-0fbcb5f983a8" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>LA1</imsld:title>
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>LA1</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-6766cc5d-a193-ba4a-6af3-5eccbd9e77ee" identifierref="resource-f6455607-038b-f81a-b59e-98c9e395eeb9" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>la1</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:learning-activity>
      <imsld:learning-activity identifier="la-fb309770-9e97-7986-213f-f866046208ac" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>LA2</imsld:title>
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>LA2</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-afdf282b-959b-bfc3-cf96-de476fc9c41c" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>la2</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:learning-activity>
      <imsld:learning-activity identifier="la-ece94eac-6168-0ffd-35fd-ebc4dc233af1" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>LA3</imsld:title>
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>LA3</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-1f48b95d-412a-2c4e-8620-aca7e0a3109b" identifierref="resource-d54d1b13-cb38-f478-a40e-bbe0d950357a" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>la3</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:learning-activity>
      <imsld:support-activity identifier="sa-fd2d3078-3468-f7a5-324c-cc438e1f2c8c" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>SA1</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-ref ref="role-0964b724-355c-49e8-a60f-58b444b29af4" />
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>SA1</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-f757db16-681a-8598-d4cd-a271c35ba503" identifierref="resource-961c7c0a-8ca4-8c20-aea2-65439c02941e" isvisible="true" />
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:support-activity>
      <imsld:support-activity identifier="sa-5566b272-8784-92c8-5429-9493f734278b" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>SA2</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-ref ref="role-0964b724-355c-49e8-a60f-58b444b29af4" />
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>SA2</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-6d2db837-6f2a-2d6b-211e-7fd04ebd94f5" identifierref="resource-f15c67c4-7a03-8ff7-0bd2-541a1859e985" isvisible="true" />
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:support-activity>
      <imsld:support-activity identifier="sa-5ebeaf81-2f76-a6f2-51c5-8f4aa1c62d0a" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>SA3</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-ref ref="role-79d92c95-7ec4-0cc0-711a-963a476e2a63" />
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>SA3</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-1a07bf78-8429-bd00-7f47-ca8904e49f99" identifierref="resource-8e804d72-e9aa-51ff-3e4a-c00a2e731aaa" isvisible="true" />
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:support-activity>
      <imsld:support-activity identifier="sa-af662654-3139-7f1d-84d1-8726d7aeb5f6" isvisible="true">
        <imsld:title>SA4</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-ref ref="role-79d92c95-7ec4-0cc0-711a-963a476e2a63" />
        <imsld:activity-description>
          <imsld:title>SA4</imsld:title>
          <imsld:item identifier="item-4a77d62c-de4a-695b-2ce4-d06520ceb327" identifierref="resource-51088ea6-51d4-7e18-f62b-76cbcb650329" isvisible="true">
            <imsld:title>sa4</imsld:title>
          </imsld:item>
        </imsld:activity-description>
      </imsld:support-activity>
    </imsld:activities>
  </imsld:components>
  <imsld:method>
    <imsld:play identifier="play-01972078-c1a1-8467-dfb0-fe8bb14d7a71" isvisible="true">
      <imsld:title>NP1</imsld:title>
      <imsld:act identifier="act-95446b8b-ee43-67ad-83ca-554220bf90d7">
        <imsld:title>Act</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-part identifier="rolepart-769ab839-497e-fdca-efa0-8c0a6cd73a65">
          <imsld:title>Role Part</imsld:title>
          <imsld:role-ref ref="role-0964b724-355c-49e8-a60f-58b444b29af4" />
          <imsld:support-activity-ref ref="sa-fd2d3078-3468-f7a5-324c-cc438e1f2c8c" />
        </imsld:role-part>
      </imsld:act>
    </imsld:play>
    <imsld:play identifier="play-5f25c22e-0387-6144-9ab4-d109aa5abb1b" isvisible="true">
      <imsld:title>NP2</imsld:title>
      <imsld:act identifier="act-55373ff5-835f-d1ba-fc3e-d069c5b27547">
        <imsld:title>Act</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-part identifier="rolepart-0269f77e-b009-3256-f12a-9742fb4462e0">
          <imsld:title>Role Part</imsld:title>
          <imsld:role-ref ref="role-79d92c95-7ec4-0cc0-711a-963a476e2a63" />
          <imsld:support-activity-ref ref="sa-5ebeaf81-2f76-a6f2-51c5-8f4aa1c62d0a" />
        </imsld:role-part>
      </imsld:act>
    </imsld:play>
    <imsld:play identifier="play-3d7ac7cb-c36b-bc8e-a841-bfc67c6f5c02" isvisible="true">
      <imsld:title>NP3</imsld:title>
      <imsld:act identifier="act-31393426-8531-1605-2ed3-d8798cd4b149">
        <imsld:title>Act</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-part identifier="rolepart-ce3e3669-90d7-8198-68d9-8bc0524f3192">
          <imsld:title>Role Part</imsld:title>
          <imsld:role-ref ref="role-0964b724-355c-49e8-a60f-58b444b29af4" />
          <imsld:support-activity-ref ref="sa-5566b272-8784-92c8-5429-9493f734278b" />
        </imsld:role-part>
      </imsld:act>
    </imsld:play>
    <imsld:play identifier="play-0d3315a1-2f25-ab0a-a461-2094fbfae9a4" isvisible="true">
      <imsld:title>NP4</imsld:title>
      <imsld:act identifier="act-4a08f369-4dea-474c-8a27-6c5d39304a7c">
        <imsld:title>Act</imsld:title>
        <imsld:role-part identifier="rolepart-bdff3654-cbb3-bdf9-063a-9d35f619a986">
          <imsld:title>Role Part</imsld:title>
          <imsld:role-ref ref="role-79d92c95-7ec4-0cc0-711a-963a476e2a63" />
          <imsld:support-activity-ref ref="sa-af662654-3139-7f1d-84d1-8726d7aeb5f6" />
        </imsld:role-part>
      </imsld:act>
    </imsld:play>
  </imsld:method>
</imsld:learning-design>
  </organizations>
  <resources>
<resource identifier="resource-44329a20-40df-d925-a31e-2579f707155d" type="webcontent" href="www.la2.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-c7f25198-8dce-d046-4594-7a2b22b5dd15" type="webcontent" href="www.alumno3.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-f6455607-038b-f81a-b59e-98c9e395eeb9" type="webcontent" href="www.la1.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-37f8f529-49c1-552c-e0a4-8aa581d93aa5" type="webcontent" href="www.profesor2.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-58164a05-d1a7-73a5-2fe9-5b3a0a9522be" type="webcontent" href="www.pruebaoverview.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-f8de38c1-d7f8-a9a5-b7a4-c737d967daf1" type="webcontent" href="www.profesor1.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-51088ea6-51d4-7e18-f62b-76cbcb650329" type="webcontent" href="www.sa4.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-8e804d72-e9aa-51ff-3e4a-c00a2e731aaa" type="webcontent" href="www.sa3.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-f15c67c4-7a03-8ff7-0bd2-541a1859e985" type="webcontent" href="www.sa2.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-d54d1b13-cb38-f478-a40e-bbe0d950357a" type="webcontent" href="www.LA3.com" />
<resource identifier="resource-961c7c0a-8ca4-8c20-aea2-65439c02941e" type="webcontent" href="www.sa1.com" />
  </resources>
</manifest>
```

i'm having trouble accessing all the nodes and the attributes, i've trying to use DOM and xmlsimple but can't correctly access all the data without some other part of the xml mixing up

with this code i manage to get some info

```html
<?PHP

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("completo.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
$xpath= new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "organizations" );
foreach( $x as $x )
{
$learningdesigns = $x->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
$learningdesign = $learningdesigns->item(0)->nodeValue;
 echo "Learning-desgin = "."$learningdesign";
print "<br>";
$learningobjectives = $x->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
$learningobjective = $learningobjectives->item(1)->nodeValue;
 echo "Learning-objective = "."$learningobjective";
print "<br>";
$items = $x->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
$item = $items->item(2)->nodeValue;
 echo "item = "."$item";
print "<br>";
}
echo "separacion -------------------------";print "<br>";


$ld = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "learning-objectives" );

foreach( $ld as $ld ) 
{ 
    $identifierref = $ld->getAttribute('identifierref'); 

    $xmltitle = $ld->getElementsByTagName( "title" ); 
    $xmltitles= $xmltitle->item(0)->nodeValue; 

    $xmlitem = $ld->getElementsByTagName( "title" ); 
    $xmlitems = $xmlitem->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    
    echo "$xmltitles - $xmlitems\n"; 
} 

?>
```

so any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using XPath pretty much. In case someone is looking for something similar, here's an example:

```html
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("imsld.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
$xpath= new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);

$nodelist = $xpath->query("//imsld:learning-design/imsld:prerequisites/imsld:title");
print  "prerequisitos = ".$nodelist->item($nodelist->length - 1)->textContent."\n";

for ($i = 1; $i < $lds; $i++)
{
$asd = $xpath->query("//imsld:learning-design/imsld:components/imsld:activities/imsld:learning-activity[".$i."]/imsld:learning-objectives/imsld:title");
print  $asd->item($asd->length - 1)->textContent."\n";
print "<br>";
}
```